# xslt apply-templates removes everything but values passed

Tags: html, xml, xslt, apply-templates

I am using `XSLT` templates to generate emails that will go out to call center. Issue I am having - transformation in `apply-templates` eliminates everything but the values. Chances are this is something trivial that I am failing to see.

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    We have just received the following Legal Services Call me back form. Please contact them as soon as possible..<br /><br /><br />
    <table border="0px">
      <tr>
        <td>Product</td>
        <td width="10px">:</td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="ShortProductName"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <xsl:if test="HasSingleOrCouple='true'">
        <tr>
          <td>Single Or Couple</td>
          <td width="10px">:</td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="SingleOrCouple"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:if>
      <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td width="10px">:</td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Firstname</td>
        <td width="10px">:</td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="Firstname"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Surname</td>
        <td width="10px">:</td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="Surname"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Telephone</td>
        <td width="10px">:</td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="Phone"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Products/ProductsItem"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="Products">
      <tr>
        <td>
          Product
        </td>
        <td width="10px">:</td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="ProductType"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="PriceLines/PriceLinesItem" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PriceLine">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="Key"/>
        </td>
        <td width="10px">:</td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="format-number(Value, '#,##0.00')"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<object>
    <HasSingleOrCouple>false</HasSingleOrCouple>
    <Title>Mrs</Title>
    <Firstname>M</Firstname>
    <Surname>Vaitke</Surname>
    <Phone>07809263588</Phone>
    <Products>
        <ProductsItem>
            <ProductType>Sale quotation</ProductType>
            <PriceLines>
                <PriceLinesItem>
                    <Key>Legal fee</Key>
                    <Value>540.8300</Value>
                </PriceLinesItem>
                <PriceLinesItem>
                    <Key>legal discount</Key>
                    <Value>0</Value>
                </PriceLinesItem>
                <PriceLinesItem>
                    <Key>Leasehold fee</Key>
                    <Value>125.0000</Value>
                </PriceLinesItem>
                <PriceLinesItem>
                    <Key>Total legal fees (excluding VAT)</Key>
                    <Value>665.8300</Value>
                </PriceLinesItem>
                <PriceLinesItem>
                    <Key>Anti money laundering (AML) checks</Key>
                    <Value>6.0000</Value>
            </PriceLinesItem>
            <PriceLinesItem>
                <Key>Lender liaison fee</Key>
                <Value>0</Value>
            </PriceLinesItem>
            <PriceLinesItem>
                <Key>Bank transfer fee</Key>
                <Value>30.0000</Value>
            </PriceLinesItem>
            <PriceLinesItem>
                <Key>Office copies</Key>
                <Value>12.0000</Value>
            </PriceLinesItem>
            <PriceLinesItem>
                <Key>Total other fees (excluding VAT)</Key>
                <Value>48.0000</Value>
            </PriceLinesItem>
            <PriceLinesItem>
                <Key>Total VAT</Key>
                <Value>142.76600</Value>
            </PriceLinesItem>
            <PriceLinesItem>
                <Key>Total (including VAT)</Key>
                <Value>856.59600</Value>
            </PriceLinesItem>
            </PriceLines>
        </ProductsItem>
    </Products>
    <IsCouple>false</IsCouple>
    <Product>Conveyancing Service</Product>
    <ShortProductName>Conveyancing</ShortProductName>
    <AdditionalPriceLines>
        <AdditionalPriceLinesItem>
            <Key>Total</Key>
            <Value>856.59600</Value>
        </AdditionalPriceLinesItem>
    </AdditionalPriceLines>
</object>
```

Result I am getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    We have just received the following Legal Services Call me back form. Please contact them as soon as possible..<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<table border="0px">
   <tr>
      <td>Product</td>
      <td width="10px">:</td>
      <td>Conveyancing</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Title</td>
      <td width="10px">:</td>
      <td>Mrs</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Firstname</td>
      <td width="10px">:</td>
      <td>M</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Surname</td>
      <td width="10px">:</td>
      <td>Vaitke</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Telephone</td>
      <td width="10px">:</td>
      <td>07809263588</td>
   </tr>
            Sale quotation


                    Legal fee
                    540.8300


                    legal discount
                    0


                    Leasehold fee
                    125.0000


                    Total legal fees (excluding VAT)
                    665.8300


                    Anti money laundering (AML) checks
                    6.0000


                Lender liaison fee
                0


                Bank transfer fee
                30.0000


                Office copies
                12.0000


                Total other fees (excluding VAT)
                48.0000


                Total VAT
                142.76600


                Total (including VAT)
                856.59600


        </table>
```

**How can I keep the html tags?**

Comment: You are applying templates to elements that do not have a matching template. Therefore the built-in template rules (that copy only the text nodes) are being applied. What is the actual result (in code, please) that you want to get?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Your question helped me solve it. Problem was `<xsl:template name="Products">` should have been `<xsl:template name="ProductsItem">` and `<xsl:template match="PriceLine">` -> `<xsl:template match="PriceLinesItem">`. Could you post it as answer please, so I could accept it.

Comment: I meant to post something very similar, but the site had an outage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am guessing correctly, you need to change:

```
<xsl:template name="Products">
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="ProductsItem">
```

*(note the change from `name` to `match`!)*

and:

```
<xsl:template match="PriceLine">
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="PriceLinesItem">
```